# Which loader responsible to load own class In JVM

Tags: java, jvm

I read the concept of JVM there is there class loader

1. Bootstrap Class loader
2. Extension Class loader
3. Application Class loader

I understand the concept of all three, But I have doubt who is responsible to load own class .

Example :

import java.lang.*;(Bootstrap Class loader)

```
class MyClass{
     public static void main(String args[]){
     -----------
     ----------------
     }
}
```

So here who is responsible for load **MyClass** here

Comment: If you “understand the concept of all three”, there should be no doubt about which loader is responsible. You don’t even need to understand it, to guess which loader is responsible for loading this class belonging to your **application**…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By elimination, it cannot be the one or the second as `MyClass` is not a JRE class, either a JRE extension.

So, `MyClass` is loaded by an Application Class loader.

To check that, you may invoke the `getClassLoader()` method on this class instance :

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println(MyClass.class.getClassLoader());
}
```

It will output something as :

> sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1d16e93

`AppClassLoader` is rather meaningful as name.

You can find some reference information on [this Oracle blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/understanding-java-class-loading) :

> **3. application class loader**
>
> 1. Loads classes from application classpath
>
> ...
>
> 6. This is the loader that loads your Java application's "main" class
>    (class with main method in it).
>
> In Sun's implementation, this is an instance of
> sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader (actually it is an inner class of
> sun.misc.Launcher class).

The blog entry is old but this point is still valid.